# How to design tree structured report using iReport 3.7.2

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

My requirenet is to build tree structured report using *iReport*. I have data base table XXX. Which is having supervisor, reportedTo columns to maintain relation among employees.

So how to generate this relation using *iReport* designer. Is there any way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a hierarchical tree](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18871388/876298)

Comment: but this link not providing required solution to me.

Answer (score 0):

iReport is not going to do this for you. Its going to be highly dependent on the DBMS you have (see recursive queries) or your ability to generate the dataset in Java.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Israel. I will take care from database end.