# How to implement the tree view?

Tags: sql, treeview, jasper-reports, db2, pivot

i have get a new task about tree. My report need implement in tree view. i don't know if there are any example for this task because i try in my report.My report also have a parameter that can select only the tree are selected. i still no get any clue.

Anyone know how to implement tree in *JasperReports*?

Comment: Possible dulicate: [How to create a hierarchical tree](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18871388/876298) & [Is Group Tree Possible in Jasper Report?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9734213/876298)

Comment: i know but the example no solution to me.i still no idea how to create that. if you can give any clue or sample report.maybe i can do it.

Comment: Why is this tagged with db2?

Comment: @IanBjorhovde Bjorhovde Because my report use the DB2 sql and have related with the tree design. i want the report show the tree design using DB2 sql.huhu